# Skip errors in the infinite Stream

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, fs2

I have an infinite `fs2.Stream` which may encounter errors. I'd like to skip those errors with doing nothing (probably log) and keep streaming further elements. Example:

```
//An example
val stream = fs2.Stream
    .awakeEvery[IO](1.second)
    .evalMap(_ => IO.raiseError(new RuntimeException))
```

In this specific case, I'd like to get infinite `fs2.Stream` of `Left(new RuntimeException)` emitting every second.

There is a `Stream.attempt` method producing the stream that got terminated after the first error is encountered. Is there a way to just skip errors and keep pulling further elements?

The `IO.raiseError(new RuntimeException).attempt` won't work in general since it would require attempting all effects in all places of the stream pipeline composition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to handle errors in the way you described.
When stream encounters the first error it is terminated. Please check this [gitter question](https://gitter.im/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2?at=5da619d380e62056e40dc5ce).

You can handle it in two ways:

1. Attempt the effect (but you already mentioned it is not possible in your case).
2. Restart stream after it is terminated:

```
val stream: Stream[IO, Either[Throwable, Unit]] = Stream
    .awakeEvery[IO](1.second)
    .evalMap(_ => IO.raiseError(new RuntimeException))
    .handleErrorWith(t => Stream(Left(t)) ++ stream) //put Left to the stream and restart it

//since stream will infinitely restart I take only 3 first values
println(stream.take(3).compile.toList.unsafeRunSync())
```